# continously loop with adding different value

Tags: php, loops, numbers

I'm new in PHP. How can i achieve continously loop with adding different value?
it's something like this

```
<?php 

   $gap1 = 2;
   $gap2 = 3;
   $lenght = 10;

   for( $i=0; $i<$length; $i++ )
   {
      //the code
   }
?>
```

and the result will be : 0  2  5  7  10  12  15  17

thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$gap1=2;
$gap2=3;
$lenght = 10;
$p=0;
for($i=0;$i<$lenght;$i++)
{
    if($i==0){$p=0;}
    elseif($i%2==0)
    {
       $p+=$gap2;
    }
    else{
          $p+=$gap1;
        }
         echo $p.'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$gap1 = 2;
   $gap2 = 3;
   $length = 10;$i=0;
    $x = 0;
   while($i<$length)
   {
      echo $x." ";
       if($i%2 == 0)
           $x+=$gap1;
       else
           $x+=$gap2;
       $i++;
   }
```

Output:

> 0 2 5 7 10 12 15 17 20 22

Answer (score 0):

```
   $gap = array(2, 3);
   $result = array(-1 => 0);
   $length = 10;

   for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $result[] = $result[$i-1] + $gap[($i) % count($gap)];
   }

   echo implode(' ', $result);
```